# Optimising a microservice to be queried with other domain data

Tags: cqrs, microservices

Consider I have these somewhat simplistic services

1. User-Service
2. DiscussionGroup-Service

A DiscussionGroup have users as members.

All of these services have their own DBs.

The UI now wants to list all users (name, profile-picture, etc) for a specific DiscussionGroup.
There could be 1000's of users per group so the result should be paginatable.

In the monolithic approach, I would have done a DB-join in the UserDAO with the DiscussionGroupMember-table. But this can't be done anymore since the DB's are separated.

What would be the best strategy to solve this in a performing way? Should I consider adding a 3rd service just for this query?

Answer (score 1):

After reading http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html stating:

> Implementing queries that join data that is now in multiple databases is challenging. There are various solutions:
>
> Application-side joins - the application performs the join rather than the database. For example, a service (or the API gateway) could retrieve a customer and their orders by first retrieving the customer from the customer service and then querying the order service to return the customer’s most recent orders.
>
> Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) - maintain one or more materialized views that contain data from multiple services. The views are kept by services that subscribe to events that each services publishes when it updates its data. For example, the online store could implement a query that finds customers in a particular region and their recent orders by maintaining a view that joins customers and orders. The view is updated by a service that subscribes to customer and order events.

I think that the CQRS approach is the most performing solution in terms of serving request/sec. This is because the User-Service could contain a materialised view of exactly that data that needs to be returned in the List queries. The materialised view is updated with the contents of the Events coming from the DiscussionGroup-Service.